# Windows 10 laptop not detecting old monitor

Tags: laptop, display

Well, I'm finally biting the bullet and working from home.  Thing is, the toy laptop that my company gives me is OK for maybe a day's worth of work, but it is just too small to work on for several days on end.  So, I dug out an old monitor from like 15 years ago and tried to hook it up.  The laptop doesn't detect it at all.  Just to be clear, it does *not* see a second display that it doesn't recognize.  It just simply doesn't detect the monitor at all.  I have found a couple of sites on the internet that give solutions, but they all involve downloading driver software.  I can tell you for certain that my company will no way no how allow me to do that.  So, I'm grasping at straws here.  Does anyone have a solution that does not involve downloading software?  The laptop is a Dell, Windows 10.  The monitor is a MAG Innovision, which works with a VGA cable. (Poor thing, was really nice back in the day).  I am connecting it to the laptop via a docking station that has a VGA port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a more modern monitor (15 years old is simply too old). Use the dock for the laptop and connect new Monitor, Keyboard and mouse to the dock.  Your company should supply these.

Followup note - I work at home as well using my own laptop (consultant).

Comment: Why would a monitor from 2005 suddenly be "too old"? The only significant change to VGA connections was EDID, and that was introduced ~25 years ago.

Comment: I would think that drivers would be an issue.